# How do I remove data that was installed as part of an iPhone App I'm devleoping?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm developing an iPhone application that's particularly large, and contains loads of videos. (Not my fault, it's on behalf of a client).

I tried to run it on my iPhone, via XCode,  not remembering I didn't have enough space on there to copy all the vids over, it errored halfway through.

However, it seems that the couple of videos it did manage to copy are still on the phone, and I now have 0 space on my phone, according to settings.

So I guess my question is where on the phones filesystem will these be stored, so that I can delete them?

EDIT: As the App didn't sucessfully install, theres no icon on the home screen for it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you look in the organizer? There is a list of installed application of your phone, check if the app still exists and delete it.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't appear there :(

Comment: You should mark your post as the answer :P just for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, eventually found it in a folder called:

```
/private/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iPhoneExplorer to explore/remove the files on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the iPhone Configuration Utility? http://support.apple.com/kb/dl926

If the app has somehow been half-installed so it has no icon, then it might still appear in this tool where you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the app on the organizer, try this:

1.- In the devices organizer, select Applications in the device.
2.- Select an application from the list of installed applications.
3.- Click Delete, and confirm that you want to remove the application.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Devices/Devices.html

Comment: It's not in Organizer unfortunately